# Firebase returns snapshot but can't access value

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Peep is always returned from the function as undefined. Can someone point me to the problem? In the success function the snapshot is returned as expected. I think it's a scoping issue.

```
function getPerson( id ) {

    var ref = new Firebase( "https://foo.firebaseio.com/people/" + id ),
    peep;

    // Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our people reference
    ref.once( "value", function( snapshot ) {
        //success
        peep = snapshot;

    }, function ( errorObject ) {
        //error
        //console.log( "The read failed: " + errorObject.code );
    });

    return peep;

}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **once()** method is asynchronous that is why callback is used. You can pass a callback as a parameter to the `getPerson function` alongside the id.

```
function getPerson(id, callback) {
  var ref = new Firebase( "https://foo.firebaseio.com/people/" + id );

  ref.once( "value", function(snapshot) {
    var peep = snapshot;
      // error will be null, and peep will contain the snapshot
      callback(null, peep);
    }, function (error) {
      // error wil be an Object
      callback(error)
  });
}

getperson('9234342', function (err, result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it should be because the success callback is not fired immediately. It receives data then get into it.

Try returning the `peep` inside the callback like.

```
return ref.once( "value", function( snapshot ) {
        //success
        peep = snapshot;
        return peep;

    }, function ( errorObject ) {
        //error
        //console.log( "The read failed: " + errorObject.code );
    });
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The `once()` method is asynchronous which is why a callback is used.  You are returning `peep` before it even has a value.  You need to return `peep` after it is defined in the callback.

```
function getPerson( id ) {

    var ref = new Firebase( "https://foo.firebaseio.com/people/" + id ),
    peep;

    // Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our people reference
    return ref.once( "value", function( snapshot ) {
        //success
        peep = snapshot;
        return peep;
    }, function ( errorObject ) {
        //error
        //console.log( "The read failed: " + errorObject.code );
    });
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
getPerson('9234342').then(function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: That `return peep` will still not work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Sorry, but this still won't work. The `return peep` returns a value, but nobody is waiting for that value. If you want, you can return the promise. Simply `return ref.once("value")`.

Comment: I added a usage section to your answer, see [this working jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qebovo/edit?js,console). Note that this requires Firebase JavaScript SDK 2.4 or higher, since it relies on promises.